# Is 'below-listed' a word & if yes can it be used with a noun to indicate its position

Tags: word-usage

Is 'below-listed' a word & if yes can it be used this way?

**"The below-listed information is for guidance purposes & might change with time, so read the T&Cs attached with the product at the time of ordering for the current information"**

Comment: Yes. I'd take it as a (verb-centred) compound adjective serving as attributive modifier of the noun "information". The past participle "listed" is the head, the first component "below" a preposition

Comment: I doubt I am alone in considering this a clumsy construction for _the information listed below_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether one would define it as a word, but it is a valid structure. One could rewrite it as: 'the information listed below', but it is common in English to change the word order so that we meet a specific word first: 'frog spawn' or 'the spawn of frogs'.

Comment: + 1 Yes, it's grammatical.